# Query SLI using Prometheus's "up" metric

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to query a server's SLI (such as 99.3%). There's an `up` Prometheus metric whose value is `1` when the server is up, and either `0` or nonexistent when the server is down. I've tried many queries such as the one shown below but they're not showing the average:

[image: Grafana screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you need [avg_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#avg_over_time) function. For example, the following query returns the average uptime of every scrape target over the last hour:

```
avg_over_time(up[1h])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't factor in when the server is down (missing values for the `up` metric). So, it always shows 100%.

Comment: When the server is down, then Prometheus should automatically generate `up=0` sample for the server - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#automatically-generated-metrics). The `up` sample may be missing only if the server is removed from the list of scrape targets in Prometheus. In this case you can use the following query for uptime: `sum_over_time(up[1h]) / (3600 / scrape_interval)`, where `scrape_interval` is the corresponding  numeric value from Prometheus config in seconds.

Comment: I'm using Grafana Agent which I believe omits data rather than setting it to `0`. Unfortunately, [this](https://i.imgur.com/8SLrXCW.png) query doesn't seem to give the SLI either.

Comment: It looks like the scrape interval in your case is 60 seconds instead of 15 seconds. You can check the real scrape interval by inspecting the duration between adjacent raw samples stored in Prometheus - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) on how to obtain raw data from Prometheus

Comment: I had [tried](https://i.imgur.com/oNuodzD.png) `60` too but it didn't look like a valid percentage.